# Is xhr always available inside onreadystatechange as a property of the argument? Which one to use?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My goal is to make a couple of XHR `onreadystatechange` handlers self-contained meaning that I'd like to get the XHR object inside them without using a closure (so I'm able to stack them in any order). Here's the main part of the code:

```
var xmlhttp;
function receiveOriginal()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = receiveOriginal;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Now, I'd like to make it like

```
function receiveOriginal()
{
    xmlhttpInside = ... // get it any way without using a closure
    if (xmlhttpInside.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpInside.status == 200)
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = receiveOriginal;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I've found out that this actually works (at least in Vivaldi and Chrome):

```
function receiveOriginal(ev)
{
    xmlhttpInside = ev.currentTarget;
    // or
    xmlhttpInside = ev.srcElement;
    // or
    xmlhttpInside = ev.target;
    // each of these return true: xmlhttp === ev.currentTarget , xmlhttp === ev.srcElement , xmlhttp === ev.target
    if (xmlhttpInside.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpInside.status == 200)
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = receiveOriginal;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But the problem is, I'm looking throught a tutorial after tutorial and all of them, even the [W3C reference](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) (this is the final one, right?), all of them say nothing about the argument passed to a `onreadystatechange` handler. So I have no idea:

- how widely is this supported?
- which one (`ev.currentTarget`, `ev.srcElement` or `ev.target`) should I use, if any? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target`, `currentTarget`, and `srcElement` are all properties of the native `Event` object ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)), which `onreadystatechange` receives (because it is an event handler). There are many ways to handle this - all of which are perfectly fine. I personally prefer to use `this` for the `onreadystatechange` callback:

```
function receiveOriginal() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nicer approach indeed :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)